# Cannot detect test object in Katalon using xpath

Tags: katalon-studio

I want to find a test object with an xpath starting with `id("foo")/`. I tried with the following line:

```
findTestObject("MyPath", [('id'), 'foo'])
```

but it doesn't work. I've already tried the most obvious solution, that is checking the property xpath and using

```
findTestObject("MyPath")
```

but it didn't work because apparently part of the xpath changes at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find your element via Selenium WebElement.

Example:

```
def driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(ById.id('elementID'))
```